# Microsoft Specialists around?

Tags: discussion

One of the benefits of http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com is the fact that there is actually a product behind it. Not all SE sites gets this benefit. Of those who do (ubuntu, SFSE, and maybe some others) one of the best things is that there are actual representatives/employees of the original product/company whom participate in the site.

In SFSE, actually one of the mods is an SF employee, and there are many others who participate.  It's like having another forum (sorry for that word) or a direct access to the "person behind the software".

I wanted to know, are there MS/Sharepoint employees here?

I know we can't force anyone to join, but this is a must.

If not - we need to make it happen. That will definitly increase the sites traffic.

Comment: Good question, deserved a upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have on more than one occasion been told by my friends close to the product group, that the product group is monitoring SPSE to see what parts of the product gives people problems.

I have also seen answers by "semi-anonymous" accounts (often created for the occasion) that clearly had inside knowledge based on the answer given.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few MVPs that participate in answering questions and many involved in the certification chain. I haven't seen anyone come out and say they are on the Sharepoint team let alone a MS employee. I believe you'll see a lot more interaction with people closer to the product team on the MSDN forums, which I personally loathe and why I choose to participate here (and thus will never have a shot at being a MVP).

Comment: If you knew the Salesforce forums, you'll understand why SFSE is so attractive ^^.